# Do I design (HTML-CSS) separately for Smart Phone, Tablet, and PC? Using Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am designing a conventional Web Portal. Do i design, header, body, footer of pages separately for the 3 platforms? Or using which classes can i make coding cross platform?

I am talking from practical standpoint. I've gone thru the http://getbootstrap.com and understand the responsive elements. But there is a choice, to either make holding class-fluid or use basic divs which do not show on alternative platforms. Hence the need of the question.

Edit: --

When I try to avoid tables, i end up using column classes `1col-lg-` which make my code (html) different for web and mobile! How do i avoid this?

```
form(name="input", action="home", method="get").form-inline.pull-right
      .row
        .col-lg-4
          label Username
        .col-lg-4
          label Password
      .row
        .col-lg-4
          input(type="text", name="user")
        .col-lg-4
          input(type="password", name="pswd")
        .col-lg-4
          input(type="submit", value="Login")
      .row
        .col-lg-5
          <input type="checkbox" checked="1" value="1" > keeps me logged in</input>
        .col-lg-5
          a(href='#') forgot your password
```

Comment: It really depends on what you need - if you planned to have a completely separate menus for phones, for example, you need to design a separate header. If not, see if you can make it using CSS only.

Comment: which platforms? For web/tablet twitter bootstrap is good choice and for mobile you look at jquery mobile

Comment: @daremachine The portal will be viewed on, all platforms obviously. I may begin with what i choose.

Comment: @Shomz I do not plan to have separate functionality at all, so the menu should be same. So a responsive-menu, with media-queries should do (taking your suggestions). Actually to avoid using tables, i had to use 1-col-lg- kind of classes for login streams, which is where the choice came in.

Comment: Great then, you seem to be on the right track. Never use tables for the design purposes. And experiment a bit with media-queries and CSS, you'll be surprised how powerful they are.

Comment: @Shomz How do i avoid col-lg- type of classes in making the login form? I've added the code in the question, for more details.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure what you want to achieve, because those classes are responsive. Speaking from a design-from-scratch perspective, make your own classes and make them centered using `margin: auto;` or `text-align: center; (on a parent div)` etc... The more you use a framework and the less it uses you, the better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 is Responsive automatically, unlike Bootstrap 2 which required extra optional .css files.  Responsive design is very subjective, and there will never be one right answer.

Designing a dedicated page based on device type gives you a much greater degree of control over what is displayed on a device, but is very labor intensive.

Responsive elements are meant to allow the same page to be served, which is much less labor, but also much less control over the output.

Your primary decision should be your target audience.  If you are going to have a web portal that you want users to have the convenience of using on their device, use the Responsive Elements.  If you are designing a site to be used on mobile devices but with an optional desktop portal, use separate dedicated pages.

**Edit**

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish exactly, but in the bootstrap 3 grid system, all items on a row should add up to 12 columns, or they start to offset and never line up correctly.  Also, you can use .col-lg-4 and .col-4 together in the same div to help with controlling how the divs stack.

Comment: ATM its primarily for the web audience so perhaps i'll go with the responsive elements. Thanks for the inputs.